# jQuery: Masonry + Sortable reorder grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using `Masonry` + jQuery `Sortable` to redesign a 3x3 grid, which you can see below.

[image]

```
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.element',
        isResizable: true,
        columnWidth: 100
    })
```

The user is able to sort the `div`s (1-4) and give them a new order.
Dragging the `div` 1 to the position top right will reorder the grid, but not as expected. After sorting it new, it will look like this:

[image]

I thought with adding event stop/start/change to sortable this way...

```
change: function(event, ui) {
               ui.item.parent().masonry('reload');
        }
```

...will reorder the grid in the way `2`, `3`, `4` on top, and below `div` 1. But it looks like the screenshot above.

Can somebody help me to do this expected behaviour?
Am I using Masonry wrong?

---

**EDIT:**
After `reload` the DOM returns `div` 2, 3, 1, 4.
I expected 2, 3, 4, 1.

---

TIA
frgtv10

Answer (score 1):

I think, im not totally sure, the masonry orders element based on the order of DOM element. when users drag an element around, do you reorder the DOM?? if not, when masonry reloads, the order still reverse the one before.

Comment: I also tried `.masonry( 'reloadItems' )`, this will `Re-collects all item elements in their current order in the DOM`. But this will not work, too. What exactly do you mean? Is the DOM wrong after reordering?

Comment: How to reorder the DOM as I want?

Comment: i thought of this problem as well, but the div 1 has a width of 300px, div 2,3,4 width of 100px. this is a bit weird, cause when i gave the div 1 a width of 200px, the div 4 will suit in the right top place. wtf? :/

Comment: you can try the column width use: `columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 3;
  }`, or try to reorder the element on drop event.

Comment: I'm reordering the element with `masonry('reload')` on event 'stop' and 'change' without success. The `ColumnWidth functin` will not have any effect.